# How to compare enum without pattern matching

Tags: enums, pattern-matching, rust

I want to apply `filter` on an iterator and I came up with this one and it works, but it's super verbose:

```
.filter(|ref my_struct| match my_struct.my_enum { Unknown => false, _ => true })
```

I would rather write something like this:

```
.filter(|ref my_struct| my_struct.my_enum != Unknown)
```

This gives me a compile error

```
binary operation `!=` cannot be applied to type `MyEnum`
```

Is there an alternative to the verbose pattern matching? I looked for a macro but couldn't find a suitable one.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Use [`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/macro.matches.html), e.g.:

```
matches!(my_struct.my_enum, Unknown)
```

Alternatively, you can use `PartialEq` trait, for example, by `#[derive]`:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum MyEnum { ... }
```

Then your "ideal" variant will work as is. However, this requires that `MyEnum`'s contents also implement `PartialEq`, which is not always possible/wanted.

Comment: Why must Rust be WILDLY different from many other languages. Couldn't have been an easy a == SomeEnum.Value noooooo, gotta have a billion other different macros and internal functionality just to compare a value. #SorryRanting

Comment: @Raid in Rust, enums may have nested values inside, which do not necessarily implement `PartialEq`. Therefore, for an _arbitrary_ enum, the compiler just can't derive `PartialEq` (and therefore support for the `==` operator) automatically. For simple enums without nested values, in theory, this could've been done, but then you will get surprising behavior when you evolve your enum and create a complex enum variant and then suddenly all equality comparisons stop working. Rust goes for the principle of less surprise/greater explicitness and requires you to write `PartialEq` explicitly.

Comment: Also, there is **no** internal functionality here - both `#[derive(PartialEq)]` and `matches!` are stable, public API, which are a part of the standard library and are very well documented.

Comment: Happen to know how to pass a Box to a parameter in a function expecting a Box<T>, but also allowing me to store that reference of a Box<T> in a different struct? I can't change an API, but also need access to that Box as well. While I have someone that knows Rust here.. lol :) (if you don't mind)

Comment: @Raid The fact that enums can carry values is one of the most amazing things about Rust. It's useful in sooo many situations, take for example [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html). So losing comparability by default is such a small price to pay, in my opinion, especially if you can achieve it anyway with `#[derive(PartialEq)]`. Also, your rant reads a little like "Oh no, why is Rust, a language who tries to fix many problems, different than the languages that have all the problems?"

Comment: @Finomnis Oh, no I get that. It's pretty useful now that I know what it all does. Just missing that normal compare for us noobs. Happen to know the question I asked Vlad? (The comment just before) about the Box<T> ? :D

Comment: @Rust Sounds like a new SO question. We shouldn't discuss off-topic.

Comment: @Raid at the beginning I was think like you. But than I see that rust is low level lang, we're coming from high level langs. Because of that rust doesn't act like others. I think this is better because this feels me like a real programmer & h*cker ;)

Answer (score 20):

I'd use pattern matching, but I'd move it to a method on the enum so that the filter closure is tidier:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Thing {
    One(i32),
    Two(String),
    Unknown,
}

impl Thing {
    fn is_unknown(&self) -> bool {
        match *self {
            Thing::Unknown => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let things = [Thing::One(42), Thing::Two("hello".into()), Thing::Unknown];
    for t in things.iter().filter(|s| !s.is_unknown()) {
        println!("{:?}", t);
    }
}
```

You can combine this with the [`matches` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/macro.matches.html) as well:

```rust
fn is_unknown(&self) -> bool {
    matches!(self, Thing::Unknown)
}
```

See also:

- [Compare enums only by variant, not value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32554285/155423)

Comment: Simple and elegant. It always seems counter-intuitive (for a Rust newbie like myself) that one can't just compare directly, but the "use pattern matching in a method" approach really goes a long way in a few short lines toward encouraging more testable, modular code..

Comment: @Shepmaster lovely! I have just learnt about Enum's _impl_ and then, I see this! Good stuff!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `if let Some(x) = option { then }` idiom with the same `if let` construct but without destructuring:

```
if let Unknown = my_struct.my_enum { false } else { true }
```

Comment: I'm surprised you can't just if my_struct.my_enum == enum_value

Comment: You can. With `#[derive(Eq)]`

Comment: It appears that you need `#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]`.

Comment: @stu The reason is that enums can carry nested values, so they can't by default be comparable with `==` because their nested value might not implement `Eq`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to use [`std::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html), which is useful if you don't care about matching `enum` data. See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=710c08971e5c57d071c7eae5d955646c):

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Thing {
    One(i32),
    Two(String),
    Unknown,
}

impl Thing {
    fn is_unknown(&self) -> bool {
        mem::discriminant(self) == mem::discriminant(&Thing::Unknown)
    }
    
    fn is_one(&self) -> bool {
        mem::discriminant(self) == mem::discriminant(&Thing::One(i32::default()))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let things = [Thing::One(42), Thing::Two("hello".to_owned()), Thing::Unknown];
    
    let known_things = things.iter().filter(|&s| !s.is_unknown());
    assert!(known_things.eq([Thing::One(42), Thing::Two("hello".to_owned())].iter()));
    
    let ones = things.iter().filter(|&s| s.is_one());
    assert!(ones.eq([Thing::One(42)].iter()));
}
```