# How to match enum variants dynamically in Rust?

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching

I have the following enum:

```
enum Token {
    Word(String),
    Semicolon,
    Comma
}
```

I do not implement `Eq`. I want to write a function to match the above through type comparisons:

```
fn expect(t: &Token, const_t: &Token) -> bool {
    match (t, const_t) {
        (&Token::Semicolon, &Token::Semicolon) => true,
        (&Token::Comma, &Token::Comma) => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

The above code is working, but has poor scalablity. If I have 100 variants, I will have a lot of helper functions and will rely on the default match `_` a lot.

I don't see an easy way to hide the different variants of the `Enum` to simply say "I want to match up the variants of two similar enums".

Are there any other workaround for this purpose?

Comment: Why are you not comparing `&Token::Word`? Should two `Word` be marked "equal" even if their content is not?

Comment: Seems likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32554285/155423

Comment: "I do not implement `Eq`."  Uh... why?

Comment: @Shepmaster No... and yes I don't care the value as well, but I have already put an answer for that question. My question is further: how can I reduce the code I have to write as I only need to say "I want to match that both side of the tuple are in the SAME variant, but I don't want to say All those variant's names"

Comment: @DK to make it more generic. Sometimes we don't want to have `Eq` and maybe the `Eq` is not what we want.

Comment: @EarthEngine did you read the *entire* answer? Including the part that is "here's a macro to automatically generate the match function based on the enum definition"?