# Check PartialEq on enum without check the attached data of the variant

Tags: enums, rust

Let say for example that this is a Json parser and to represent each variant of the possible data which contains I use an enum.

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum JsonObject {
    Invalid,
    Null,
    Bool(boo),
    /// etc
}
```

Now the in some part of the code I compare two JsonObjects

```rust
let type1 = JsonObject::Bool(true);
let type2 = JsonObject::Bool(false);

if type1 == type2 {
    // do stufff
}
```

The problem is that `type1 != type2` because `JsonObject::Bool(true) != JsonObject::Bool(false)`, What I want is that the enum does not compare the inner data of the variant and just the variant itself.
`JsonObject::Bool(_) == JsonObject::Bool(_)`

Answer (score 4):

Derived `PartialEq` by default will compare everything, including wrapped values as you have noticed.

For custom behaviour, you must implement it manually.

Luckily, Rust `1.21.0` and up has a function for this, [`std::mem::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html):

```
use std::{
    cmp::PartialEq,
    mem::discriminant,
};

impl PartialEq for JsonObject {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        discriminant(self) == discriminant(other)
    }
}
```

---

Older answer

```
use std::cmp::PartialEq;

impl PartialEq for JsonObject {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        use JsonObject::*;
        match (self, other) {
            (Invalid, Invalid) => true,
            (Null, Null) => true,
            (Bool(_), Bool(_)) => true,
            _ => false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `mem::discriminant` for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554285/compare-enums-only-by-variant-not-value

Comment: @trentcl thank you, I updated my answer, although what you linked to looks more complete as an `QA`, wouldn't it be better to close this as dupe altogether?

Comment: Mmm, arguable, your answer explains why deriving `PartialEq` is wrong, but it could go either way IMO. I'll vote it and we'll see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 2):

With [`strum`](https://docs.rs/crate/strum/0.19.2) crate you can do like that

```rust
extern crate strum;
#[macro_use]
extern crate strum_macros;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, EnumDiscriminants)]
enum JsonObject {
    Invalid,
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    // etc
}

impl std::cmp::PartialEq for JsonObject {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        JsonObjectDiscriminants::from(self) == other.into()
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to [trentcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466669/check-partialeq-on-enum-without-check-the-attached-data-of-the-variant/63467129#comment112229242_63467129), works perfectly without additional dependencies

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum JsonObject {
    Invalid,
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    // etc
}

impl std::cmp::PartialEq for JsonObject {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        use std::mem::discriminant;
        discriminant(self) == discriminant(other)
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert!(JsonObject::Bool(true) == JsonObject::Bool(false));
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `strum` is supposed to be for but this seems like way overkill when `mem::discriminant` exists

Comment: @trentcl wow, never knew!