# How do I conditionally check if an enum is one variant or another?

Tags: enums, rust, conditional-statements

I have an enum with two variants:

```
enum DatabaseType {
    Memory,
    RocksDB,
}
```

What do I need in order to make a conditional if inside a function that checks if an argument is `DatabaseType::Memory` or `DatabaseType::RocksDB`?

```
fn initialize(datastore: DatabaseType) -> Result<V, E> {
    if /* Memory */ {
        //..........
    } else if /* RocksDB */ {
        //..........
    }
}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

First have a look at the free, official Rust book [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book), specifically [the chapter on enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html).

---

## `match`

```rust
fn initialize(datastore: DatabaseType) {
    match datastore {
        DatabaseType::Memory => {
            // ...
        }
        DatabaseType::RocksDB => {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

## `if let`

```rust
fn initialize(datastore: DatabaseType) {
    if let DatabaseType::Memory = datastore {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

## `==`

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum DatabaseType {
    Memory,
    RocksDB,
}

fn initialize(datastore: DatabaseType) {
    if DatabaseType::Memory == datastore {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

## `matches!`

This is available since Rust 1.42.0

```rust
fn initialize(datastore: DatabaseType) {
    if matches!(datastore, DatabaseType::Memory) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to compare enum without pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25576748/155423)
- [Read from an enum without pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45473656/155423)
- [Compare enums only by variant, not value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32554285/155423)
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html

Comment: It's silly that in order to check one variant of the enum with ==, you have to derive(PartialEq) while it does essentially the same as the other examples.
Also, the if let<type> = <value> syntax is completely counter-intuitive. Assigning a value to a type doesn't make sense.
The fact that they created the matches! macro, kind of proves my point.

Answer (score 3):

```
// A simple example that runs in rust 1.58:
enum Aap {
    Noot(i32, char),
    Mies(String, f64),
}

fn main() {
    let aap: Aap = Aap::Noot(42, 'q');
    let noot: Aap = Aap::Mies(String::from("noot"), 422.0);
    println!("{}", doe(aap));
    println!("{}", doe(noot));
}

fn doe(a: Aap) -> i32 {
    match a {
        Aap::Noot(i, _) => i,
        Aap::Mies(_, f) => f as i32,
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you want to modify your example, but it's worth pointing out that if one of the variants is a struct with named fields (say, `Noot { a: i32, b: char }`) then one matches using `..` instead of `_`.

Answer (score 2):

As of Rust 1.21.0, you can use [std::mem::discriminant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html) to check against an enum variant instead of by value:

```rust
use std::mem;

enum Foo { A(&'static str), B(i32), C(i32) }

assert_eq!(mem::discriminant(&Foo::A("bar")), mem::discriminant(&Foo::A("baz")));
```